# What does recruit mean in this context?

Tags: word-usage

> The natural sciences had not yet made their appearance in Swedish
> universities, but Åbo Akademi led the field in theological research at
> the end of the seventeenth century. So the classical languages were
> highly regarded even in Åbo: all dissertations were printed and
> publicly defended in Latin or Greek. Academic interest in the national
> languages was not on the same level, despite the fact that both clergy
> and civil servants needed them in their daily work. Teaching in
> preparatory and grammar schools was conducted in Swedish. This,
> together with a Swedish-language central government, led to a
> substantial Swedification of the educated elite in Finland, which
> until then had been mainly **recruited** from the Finnish-speaking
> peasantry
>
> (bolds by me)
>
> A history of Finland by Henrik Meinander

My opinion is that the "educated elite" had been recruited from the Finnish-speaking peasanty.
But what does it mean to recruit en elite?

Comment: You hire someone to work for you, this is what recruit means.

Comment: The class of people who were literate and had better jobs had come mainly from Finnish-speaking farming families. Presumably they were 'recruited' in the sense that intelligent people were selected to receive an education and go on to professional or administrative jobs.

Comment: It's unclear. It could be like Kate said that the educated elite were literally selected from among the Finnish-speaking peasantry, or it could be used more figuratively to just mean the educated elite *came from* the Finnish-speaking peasantry, with no recruitment taking place. The writing is not clear enough to give a definite answer.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recruit

Answer (score 1):

The author simply means that the composition of the "intellectual elite" began to change.  Previously, they had come from the "Finnish-speaking peasantry", but during and after a "substantial Swedification", Swedish speakers were also becoming part of the "elite".

Even though we think of "recruiting" as an active, transitive verb, there is not a strong implication here that a particular person or group of people was intentionally doing the "recruiting".  Unintentional, collective actions or effects are sometimes described with active verbs in the passive voice, or with participle adjectives (verb + -ed as a describing word).

The sentence is very close in meaning to the following:

"This, together with a Swedish-language central government, led to a substantial Swedification of the educated elite in Finland, which until then had mainly **come from** from the Finnish-speaking peasantry."

Answer (score 0):

**Recruit** is used figuratively to state that the source of the educated elite was primarily the Finnish-speaking peasantry.

It's an interesting choice of words because you technically can't recruit anyone into "the educated elite" because it doesn't really exist. So it's possible that the author chose that word imply that there was some kind of proactive effort to educate the Finnish-speaking peasantry so they could become part of the educated elite.

That also might be reading much more into it than was ever intended!